# How to solve 'Failed to register for remote notifications', to receive push notifications on an iOS game that has built by 'Unity Cloud Build'

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, unity3d-cloud-build

We use to build my project using the "Unity cloud build" service for both Android and iOS, using Firebase as our backend. Recently we decided to add the "push notification" capability to our project to enhance user experience.

I started to test things to see how the whole thing works, and I added the firebase-messaging packages and the standard "official" code to receive and save the token. Also I made a little "sender" code using "Firebase functions" to send test notifications.

The Android build has no problem, it worked right away. It received the token, and whenever I use that token to send test notification, the notification pops up immediately with no problem.

But we have some problems with iOS version! It not worked! It's very vague where the problem is and I couldn't find any similar problem using Google!! We spent lots of time on tweaking .p12 and the provisioning files and .p8 file (for APN connection with firebase), they all look fine and we're not sure if the problem is there!

This is how the iOS version behave:

1. The log shows that the device connected to FCM and received a token, but right after that line, there is always an error line: `Failed to register for remote notifications`
2. When I send a message to that token it doesn't show any notification, only in the log, I can see this: `FCM: Received message`

Also, this is my iOS settings on Unity for enabling remote notifications:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEb36.png)

And this is my post-build script on Unity cloud build

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;
using System.IO;

public class BuildSettings
{
    [PostProcessBuild]
    public static void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget buildTarget, string path)
    {
        if (buildTarget != BuildTarget.iOS)
            return;
        string projectPath = path + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";
        PBXProject project = new PBXProject();
        project.ReadFromFile (projectPath);
        string targetGuid = project.TargetGuidByName(PBXProject.GetUnityTargetName());
        project.AddCapability(targetGuid, PBXCapabilityType.PushNotifications);
        project.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "CoreBluetooth.framework", false);
        project.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "UserNotifications.framework", false);
        File.WriteAllText (projectPath, project.WriteToString ());

        var plistPath = Path.Combine(path, "Info.plist");
        var plist = new PlistDocument();
        plist.ReadFromFile(plistPath);
        plist.root.SetString("NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription", "Bluetooth connection message!");
        plist.WriteToFile(plistPath);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further investigation revealed that the problem has emerged in lack of aps-environment entitlement, the process of adding this entitlement to your iOS build is different if you use Xcode or cloud build.

You can find the solution to this here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-put-ios-entitlements-file-in-a-unity-project.442277/